# Trying to find a great sound FX pack that aims at Trailers

Tags: sound-effects, sound-libraries, sound-design, trailer

Anybody know of any great sound Fx packs that are great for designing sound for film trailers. Like rises, impacts, and stingers, etc.

Answer (score 3):

The BOOM Cinematic Trailer Construction Kit is great for what you're looking for.

Answer (score 0):

I keep procrastinating on buying that! haha is it worth it I really would love to talk to someone who used it. The one effect I have been trying to find is that steady rise where it sounds like strings being stretched out or a screaming crescendo

Comment: Pretty sure there's something like that in there. I had put off getting it for awhile and wish I hadn't. It's got some really great stuff in it. Use it all the time now.

Answer (score 0):

A classic is the Sound Designer Tool Kit 1 & 2. Pretty standard and signature stuff for trailers.

Answer (score 0):

I use booms trailers construction kit daily. The cinematic metals is also very useful

Answer (score 0):

I haven't got the cinematic trailer construction kit but Cinematic metal, Creatures and Wildcats get used often, both the designed and the constructions kits. I guess as mentioned already here Cinematic trailer construction kit is what your looking for. +1 for Boom Library :)

Answer (score 0):

Add "The Great Whoosh" from Sound Ideas.

Answer (score 0):

Noise Generator has 3 fantastic sets, a smidge pricy but very fresh-sounding material.  The Designer Sound Library has some great fresh material too.  Both are on Sound Ideas site.  I have a free sample pack that Boom offered up a while back for this Cinematic Trailers set and it's pretty good stuff from the samples I heard.

I personally like to seek out fresh stuff, only because I feel like I have a stomach ache every time I hear that same Koto drum (the one with the echo) or that same vocal whoosh scream with the anvil-like sound.

Answer (score 0):

check out the desolated strings and wood from www.thesoundcatcher.com maybe this is it what you´re for.

Answer (score 0):

some of the radio imaging libraries have stuff that really runs down road pretty well.